# How I can get last (actual) transaction status in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I try to get actual transaction status in Shopware 6. I try to use this code  `$paymentStatus = $order->get('transactions')->first()->get('stateMachineState')->get('technicalName');` but here is a problem. `transactions` have many statuses inside array and if I choose first() sometimes it's wrong status.
For example (it's real example) we have order. The order has 3 transaction statuses in time which a customer held:

1. Open
2. Cancelled
3. Paid

if I use code which was mentioned above I get Cancelled status (because it's first element of array) but I expect Paid. I have only one solution it's sort array by transaction createdAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction with the highest creation time is the current transaction of an order. For example this is how Shopware determines the order payment status on the account orders page:

First transactions are sorted ascending ([AccountOrderPageLoader](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/c8f04a4ef6189f5b87767bd52b27310635204e2d/src/Storefront/Page/Account/Order/AccountOrderPageLoader.php#L138)):

```php
$criteria
    ->getAssociation('transactions')
    ->addSorting(new FieldSorting('createdAt'));
```

Then the last transaction is used for the payment status of an order ([order-item.html.twig](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/c8f04a4ef6189f5b87767bd52b27310635204e2d/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/account/order-history/order-item.html.twig#L232)):

```
<span class="order-table-body-value">{{ order.transactions|last.stateMachineState.translated.name }}</span>
```

You can do the same. Sort your transactions ascending and then get the status of the last one:

```php
$paymentStatus = $order->getTransactions()->last()->getStateMachineState()->getTechnicalName();
```

Comment: one question: is it better use createdAt or updatedAt?

Comment: @Stepan I would use the same logic as Shopware, so `createdAt`.